# ERROR: column mm.geom does not exist in PostgreSQL execution using R

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I am trying to run the model in R software which calls functions from GRASS GIS (version 7.0.2) and PostgreSQL (version 9.5) to complete the task. I have created a database in PostgreSQL and created an extension Postgis, then imported required vector layers into the database using Postgis shapefile importer. Every time I try to run using R (run as an administrator), it returns an error like:

> Error in fetch(dbSendQuery(con, q, n = -1)) : 
>     error in evaluating the argument 'res' in selecting a method for function 'fetch': Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
>     RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column mm.geom does not exist
>   LINE 5:   (st_dump(st_intersection(r.geom, mm.geom))).geom as geom,
>                                              ^
>   HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "r.geom".

QUERY:

```
insert into m_rays
with os as (
        select r.ray, st_endpoint(r.geom) as s,
        (st_dump(st_intersection(r.geom, mm.geom))).geom as geom,
        mm.legend, mm.hgt as hgt, r.totlen
        from rays as r,bh_gd_ne_clip as mm
        where st_intersects(r.geom, mm.geom)
)
select os.ray, os.geom, os.hgt, l.absorb, l.barrier, os.totlen,
st_length(os.geom) as shape_length, st_distance(os.s, st_endpoint(os.geom)) as near_dist
from os left join lut as l
on os.legend = l.legend
```

> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function do_crtn(text,text,text) line 30 at EXECUTE

I have checked over and over again, column geometry does exist in Schema>Public>Views of PostgreSQL. Any advise on how to resolve this error?

Comment: Have you tried changing mm to r in your query?

Comment: Columns don't exist in scheme, they exist in tables which exist in scheme.

Comment: @kpie: No, I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @Jakub: Thanks for the correction. Just added the exact location of geometry columns.

Comment: @JibranKhan Now please post the definition of `bh_gd_ne_clip` view and any relevant tables.

Comment: @Jakub: It is one of the many vector layers (input files) to run the model. Location: Schemas>public>Tables>bh_gd_ne_clip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add quotes and then use `r."geom"` instead `r.geom`